# scala testing with unmanaged dependencies

Tags: scala

A Scala application has unmanaged dependencies, defined in Build.scala as shown below. No compile error and it works properly. now I want to add some test cases. how to add these unmanaged dependencies for testing ?

```
lazy val applicationPrj = Project(
    id = "AAA",
    base = file("AAA")
  ) dependsOn (List(utilsPrj, jmsPrj).map(_ % defaultProjectScopeInheritance): _*) settings(
    globalSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= coreTestDeps ++ appDep ,    
    assemblySettings,
    unmanagedJars in Compile ++= unmanagedLib,
    unmanagedJars in Test ++= unmanagedLib //NOT work 
  )

  val appDep = Seq(  
    ....
  )

  val unmanagedLib  = {
    val tempDefJarPath = new File("temp\\lib\\") ** "*.jar"
    tempDefJarPath.classpath
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try "Manual Dependency Management" from http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html? Replace `Compile` with `Test` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @radumanolescu. I wanted to have unmanaged libs in tests scope only and your suggestion works as charm - I just defined a custom `unamangedJars in Test`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, JARs that you put in `lib` are added to all classpaths, including tests: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html

Unless I misunderstand, you should be able to see `lib/MyLib.jar` from your test cases. You can print the classpath from one of your tests to check that:

```
val cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path")
val sep = System.getProperty("path.separator")
cp.split(sep).foreach(println)
```